# MediaPlayerElement vs MediaElement Which one to choose?

Tags: audio, uwp

I have gone through the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730683/uwp-mediaplayerelement-vs-mediaelement) provided here for the difference. But I need to just play notification sound for like 2 seconds as an alert. No video or any other heavy loading.

This is the notification sound I am about to play.

```
ms-winsoundevent:Notification.SMS
```

The below is for MediaPlayerElement:

```
MediaPlayerElement mediaPlayerElement = new MediaPlayerElement();
mediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(new Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer { AudioCategory = Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayerAudioCategory.Alerts});
mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.AudioCategory = Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayerAudioCategory.Alerts;
mediaPlayerElement.Source = Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Default"));
mediaPlayerElement.AutoPlay = false;
mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
```

The below is for MediaElement:

```
MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
mediaElement.AudioCategory = AudioCategory.Alerts;
mediaElement.Source = new Uri("ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Default");
mediaElement.AutoPlay = false;
mediaElement.Play();
```

Can I use MediaElement since its a small audio or should I only use MediaPlayerElement as it is the one prescribed by Microsoft? which one is better to use in this case?

P.S.: I need to set audio category as Alerts in order to dim any background music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use MediaElement since its a small audio or should I only use MediaPlayerElement as it is the one prescribed by Microsoft? which one is better to use in this case?

Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement#remarks),

> In Windows 10, build 1607 and on we recommend that you use `MediaPlayerElement` in place of `MediaElement`. `MediaPlayerElement` has the same functionality as `MediaElement`, while also enabling more advanced media playback scenarios. Additionally, all future improvements in media playback will happen in `MediaPlayerElement`.

And it means that the new feature will be developed base on the `MediaPlayerElement`,  we recommend using `MediaPlayerElement` that could make your app has longer life.